# How to change main title to the name of a selected list item with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the main title by the name of the selected / active list? For example, if I select "Item A" I would like the main title to change to "Item A", if I select "Sub item A1" the main title changes to "Sub item A1 and so on with the rest of the items. But the title must also restore to original name when no list item is active/selected How can I achieve that with jquery?

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".down").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.container {
  background: silver;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.title {
  background: #94a2e4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
.list{font-size: 20px;}
.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 230px;
}
.caret-down::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
.down {
  display: none;
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Change titlet</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Item A<span class="caret">
        <ul class="down">
          <li>Sub item A1</li>
          <li>Sub item A2</li>
          <li>Sub etc.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item B<span class="caret">
        <ul class="down">
          <li>list etc.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: _'if I select "Sub item A1"'_ - your code doesn't currently allow to actually "select" that in any way. You are handling clicks on the `.caret` elements only.

Comment: "*the title must also restore to original name when no list item is active/selected*" - how are you expecting to "unselect" an item?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, so here's my interpretation of what I suspect you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/cz23ngp1/  `$(".caret .down li").click(function() { $(".title > h1").text($(this).text()); return false; });`

Comment: @freedomn-m If this is the result I'm looking for. But only the sub items of the list are shown. Is it possible to display the titles "Item A" and "Item B"?

Comment: `.text($(this).parent().text())` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

No need for jquery. All you need to do is add a click event to all the li in .down. You can do that by selecting them all, adding that event. In that event you can then set the text of the title.

```
const title = document.querySelector(".title > h1");

const downItems = document.querySelectorAll(".down > li");

for (const downItem of downItems) {
  downItem.addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stops the parent from closing
    title.innerText = event.target.innerText;
  });
}
```